# Non-Blocking parallel processing and pass data each other

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc, spring-data-jpa, rx-java2

I want to make parallelism each parent and child entities, in a process which must be return quickly `childEntities`.  So I couldn't decide clearly, which way is suitable for this process. Because in that parallel threads also calls http call and springdataRepository's `save` method one time(I will manage thread size because of JDBC connection pool size).

By the way, I have just tried RxJava-2 library yet.

I expected that -> If a parallel flow process throws an exception, `onErrorResumeNext`method (or near something) must be go on and complete all process after exception. But it suspends the flow completely.

So what I need -> Completely Non/Blocking parallel flows, if one of throws exception, just catch it and then continue the rest of the parallel process.

Any ideas ? Any other solution ideas is acceptable.(Like manual thread management)

That is what I tried, but not working as expected.

```
package com.mypackage;

import io.reactivex.Flowable;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Slf4j
public class TestApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<String> createdParentEntities = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> erroredResponses = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> childEntities = new ArrayList<>();

        Flowable.range(1, 100) // 100: is not fixed normalle
                .parallel(100) // It will be changed according to size
                .runOn(Schedulers.io())
                .map(integer -> createParentEntity(String.valueOf(integer)))
                .sequential()
                .onErrorResumeNext(t -> {
                    System.out.println(t.getMessage());
                    if (t instanceof Exception) {
                        erroredResponses.add(t.getMessage());
                        return Flowable.empty();
                    } else {
                        return Flowable.error(t);
                    }
                })
                .blockingSubscribe(createdParentEntities::add);

        if (!createdParentEntities.isEmpty()) {
            Flowable.fromIterable(createdParentEntities)
                    .parallel(createdParentEntities.size())
                    .runOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .doOnNext(TestApp::createChildEntity)
                    .sequential()
                    .blockingSubscribe(childEntities::add);
        }

        System.out.println("====================");
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
        log.info("Total Time : " + time);

        log.info("TOTAL CREATED ENTITIES : " + createdParentEntities.size());
        log.info("CREATED ENTITIES " + createdParentEntities.toString());
        log.info("ERRORED RESPONSES " + erroredResponses.toString());
        log.info("TOTAL ENTITIES : " + childEntities.size());
    }

    public static String createParentEntity(String id) throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(1000); // Simulated for creation call
        if (id.equals("35") || id.equals("75")) {
            throw new Exception("ENTITIY SAVE ERROR " + id);
        }
        log.info("Parent entity saved : " + id);
        return id;
    }

    public static String createChildEntity(String parentId) throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(1000);// Simulated for creation call
        log.info("Incoming entity: " + parentId);
        return "Child Entity:  " + parentId + " parentId";
    }
}
```

Comment: When `onError()` is called in an observer chain, the chain is finished; no more data values will be issued. You can use the `retry()` operator to re-subscribe to the observable when an error occurs, or use the `retryWhen()` operator to take different actions based on the type of error.

Comment: @BobDalgleish I don't want to retry , just want to collect errors. Is it a usable process retry for this really ?

Comment: If you want your observable source to continue to emit values after an error, you will need to catch the error at source and collect them in a different manner than using an observer chain. Once `onError()` is called, the observer chain is done. That is how an observer chain works.